# What’s the proper way to handle an AJAX call behind Symfony 4 firewall?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I need to send AJAX requests to parts of my website where my user is authenticated. Unfortunately, Symfony 4 rejects those requests (and sends them to login page) as it doesn’t detect it as authenticated access to my controller/route.

How do you make sure your ajax requests gets through Symfony 4 access control ?
In my security.yaml i have configured the security as follow:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I need to access /profile/update with an ajax call. How do I provide credentials to symfony?

Thanks!

Comment: "it doesn’t detect it as authenticated"...what actual error do you get? Are you sending any kind of authentication information with your request?

Comment: Also, do you have different firewalls? Bear in mind that if your user authenticates in one firewall it won't be automatically authenticated in a second one. Once the user is authenticated, an ajax call is no different than a non ajax call, so my suggestions would be to check if your user can access that url without ajax, that might help you find the issue.

Comment: In my opinion if you do not want an ajax call to be redirected to the login page you shouldn't use the access_control. Instead you can secure your controller like you can see in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, please let me know.

Comment: Yes! Thank you Stephan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller method redirects the Ajax call to the login page, because your JS doesn't send credentials (read: cookies).

If you're using fetch, use `credentials`:

```
fetch(url, {
  credentials: "same-origin"
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials

If you're using another way to create the Ajax call, please update your question with some JS code and let me know :).

If you don't want to redirect the user to the login page when executing an XMLHttpRequest ('ajax'), use this listener to send a 403 response instead:

```
class AjaxAuthenticationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => [
                ['onCoreException', 10],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function onCoreException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        $request   = $event->getRequest();

        if (! $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (! ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) && ! ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedException)) {
            return;
        }

        $event->setResponse(new Response('No access', 403));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stephan for your detailed answer! Very helpful